# Page not loaded in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, playframework, windows-xp, playframework-2.1, securesocial

I get this problem when I am trying to run a java project using play 2.1.0. with securesocial 2.0.12

"    No data received
    Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no data.
    Here are some suggestions:
    Reload this webpage later.
    Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without       sending any data.   "

I had recently installed play 2.1.0 in place of play 2.0.4. I just changed the environment variable PATH to point to the location of my new play 2.1.0 folder.I am using windows XP  and running it on google chrome.

Answer (score -1):

try with other browsers. if you get same error change ssl(https to http) in securesocial